# Potentiometer part number to Identify (pot, 1k, 3/8" single turn)

Tags: potentiometer

I want to know what the part number of this specific potentiometer, 1k, 3/8" single turn there is code written on the surface of the body says T20YM and 102C417.
I would like to know the part number, manufacturing part number, and where I can buy it, please hopefully you can help me.

[image]

Comment: have you googled either of the part numbers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, since OP didn't do any research of their own.

Comment: @Velvet I can't find anything in the question that supports OP did or didn't do research.

Comment: @MiNeMe A simple Google/Duckduckgo/Startpage search for the term 'T20YM' nets plenty of good results. Nothing obscure. Nothing hidden.

Comment: @Velvet True it's not hidden, but then try go deeper. One datasheet that I found, and it's not too detailed about the part-numbers composition.

Comment: @Velvet Thank you. And I'm not far from supporting to close, due to the lack of response from Op.

Answer (score 2):

Vishay - Sfernice

Part.nr T20YM-102-D06
T20 = Series
YM = Style (top adjust, pin style)
102 = 1000 Ohm
Last 3 chars don't know, possibly tolerance and Watt, the only datasheet available won't tell.

Marking on the trimpot
102 should be the same as above, C unknown, 417 Mfr date 2004 week 17.